# Do animals have a religion?

Tags: animals, religion

Are humans the only living creature that have a religion or do animals have a religon?
Is it wrong to say an animal is muslim?

Comment: Let me only say they are not all the same, we have Ahadeeth that say some stones (like Aqiq) have preceded th other stones in confessing the uniqueness of Allah, the prophethood of the holy prophet and the Wilayah of Imam Ali peace be upon them. Also about the fruits we have similar Ahadeeth that differ between sour fruits and sweet fruits in this respect, also about animals and etc., but non of these mean animals or stones have religion like we do have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since animals don't have brains to think and decide whether this is good or bad, So there is no religion for animals. since as we know the most basic rule in religion is to think in GOD:

> تفكر ساعة خير من عبادة سنة
>
> Thinking an hour is better than doing year worship

this is a logical answer.

If we want to talk in religion point of view there is no say or no Aya to prove that.

Comment: Animals have no brain? They don't think and decide? Sure the have brain and they do think and decide, but the scope of their thought and decision is more limited than ours, and of course they have brain.

Comment: There is a hadith where the Prophet (PBUH) say that he met a lion and told him he is the messenger of Allah and so the lion didnt harm him instead he helped him by showing hum the way to the main road. Also I have heard that spiders and a bird helped the Prophet (PBUH) by spining their web around the cave to make it look like an old place that no one had been and they bird layed an egg there.

Comment: @Aisha, about the lion Hadeeth that you referred we have several such Ahadeeth, even in some Ahadeeth the animal talked with the holy prophet (like they did to David and Solomon peace be upon them) and confessed in his prophethood ...

Answer (score 5):

Every creature worships Allah,

> And to Allah prostrates whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on the earth of creatures, and the angels [as well], and they are not arrogant. [[16:49](http://quran.com/16/49)]

except humans and Jinns, who take advantage of their free will to **choose** whether to worship Allah or not. A Muslim is who **willfully** submits himself/herself to Allah.

So, probably we cannot call animals muslims, because they donot ***choose to worship*** Allah, they just do it, maybe because they are made like that. But all of them worship Allah, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Only those creature need religion, who have conscious.. Jinn and men, no other needs religion.. as only they are given intllect to chose from good and bad.

Answer (score -2):

Do Animals Invent , Discover , Some Thing !

Do Animals are as much intelligent as Human !

They only do what they programmed to do by Creator. lion can never eat grass ! By default They all submit their Will to AllAH.
They all are Muslim.

Listen to Quran

https://youtu.be/LsIAlnr5CZk